# Describe the nonzero integer solutions to the equation $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 + e^3 + f^3 + g^3 =0$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Can someone describe all the integer solutions to the above equation such that $abcdefg\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Here's one solution that I thought of $(-1,-1,-1,-2,-2,-2,3)$. Multiplying each term by $-1$ also works.

Comment: unlikely to describe all. Where do you get these questions?

Comment: However, there are ways to generate some of them.

Comment: @ NoChance, may you kindly outline the ways, at least that would be some progress.

Comment: Take a look at:https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/010, some of the expressed formulas could help.

Comment: In addition to my other note, the fact that the sum of cubes equals the square of the sum is interesting and may help you: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5257.pdf

Comment: The formula is long. It You exactly need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the equation.

$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3+x_5^3+x_6^3=x_7^3$$

You can write a fairly simple formula.

$$x_1=t^2-3(k+s)(p+t)-3p^2+2u$$

$$x_3=t^2-3(p+s)(k+t)-3k^2+2u$$

$$x_5=t^2-3(p+k)(s+t)-3s^2+2u$$

$$x_2=2t^2+3((k+s)(p-t)-2pt)+3p^2+u$$

$$x_4=2t^2+3((p+s)(k-t)-2kt)+3k^2+u$$

$$x_6=2t^2+3((p+k)(s-t)-2st)+3s^2+u$$

$$x_7=3(t^2-2(p+k+s)t+u)$$

where,

$$u=3(p^2+k^2+s^2)$$

Cube certainly look nice, but I prefer to solve such equations. Look cumbersome, but the solution much simpler.  [The sum of the cubes and the amount of combinations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855271/the-sum-of-the-cubes-and-the-amount-of-combinations/856180#856180)

Comment: You can always simplify expressions by using substitutions.

Comment: Care to explain where did the substitution formula came from?

Comment: @NoChance: It's just by inspection. If you look at his [version 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1588504/1), you can see how the expressions for the $x_i$ can easily be shortened by using the variable $u$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a known way of describing all of them, but here you'll find some further reading: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicNumber.html

Answer (score -1):

Regarding equation,  (a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 + e^3 + f^3 = g^3 )

The above equation has parametrization given below:

(a,b,c,d,e,f)^3=

[(6k^2+12k-18),(k^2-2k+49),(5k^2+38k+5),(8k^2+16k-24),
       (7k^2-14k-41),(10k^2+20k-30)]^3 = [(13k^2+22k+13)]^3= (g)^3

For k=2 we have:

(30,49,101,40,-41,50)^3=(109)^3