# An identity form: $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3=y_1^3+y_2^3+y_3^3+y_4^3$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I found an identity form: $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3=y_1^3+y_2^3+y_3^3+y_4^3$ as follows:
$$(a+b+c)^3+a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b)^3+(b+c)^3+(c+a)^3+(6y)^3$$

Where $abc=36y^3$

Poof of this identity is very simple. But the identity nice.

> Which reference of the identity? can generalized of the identity?

Comment: see here https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/001a

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588122/describe-the-nonzero-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-a3-b3-c3-d3/1588504#1588504

Comment: See (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (shown below) has parametrization:

$(a+b+c)^3+a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b)^3+(b+c)^3+(c+a)^3+(6y)^3$

$(y,a,b,c)=((8)(3k-4),(256),(24)(3k-4),(3)(3k-4)^2)$

For $k=2$, we get:  $(3,12,64,79)^3=(15,24,67,76)^3$